# How to generate thumb pdf file only first page in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, socket.io

I have issue When I upload  pdf file in multiple page then generate thumb multiple time.

my code is below

```
var image = random() + '.png';
imagename = 'uploads/document_thumb/' + image;
var pathToFile = path.join(__dirname, req.files[i].path)
, pathToSnapshot = path.join(__dirname, '/uploads/document_thumb/' + image);

    im.resize({
            srcPath: pathToFile
        , dstPath: pathToSnapshot
        , width: 150
        , height: 150
        , quality: 0
        , gravity: "North"
    }, 
   function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
            }
    console.log('resized image', pathToSnapshot);
    });
```

How to set generate only one page thumb generate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I Use GraphicsMagick for generate thumb of Pdf File.

```
  var gm = require('gm');
    var image = random() + '.png';
        var pathToFile = path.join(__dirname, req.files[i].path)
        , pathToSnapshot = path.join(__dirname, '/uploads/document_thumb/' + image);
        gm(pathToFile).thumb(150, // Width
                            150, // Height
                            pathToSnapshot, // Output file name
                            40, // Quality from 0 to 100
        function (error, stdout, stderr, command) {
            if (!error) {
                        console.log(command);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Is This convert only pdf?? Can I able to convert docx into thumbnail?

Comment: Yes, this use only PDF