# How to generate thumb from doc file first page in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, thumbnails, docx

I need to generate document first page into thumbnail view. I have searched in Stackoverflow

[How to generate thumb pdf file only first page in node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38410079/how-to-generate-thumb-pdf-file-only-first-page-in-node-js)

Can i able to use this for docx to thumbnail or is any other way to do that?

Comment: If you don't find a way to directly generate a thumbnail from a docx file, I'm sure you can convert the docx to pdf and then use GraphicsMagick to generate a thumbnail from that pdf.

Comment: Thank you so much I will try that way .. Do u know any npm to convert docx to pdf?

Comment: I haven't used used one yet, but this looks promising: https://www.npmjs.com/package/word2pdf

Comment: Ok thank you .. Have you uses GraphicsMagick. Am getting error.. When i am search it shows that I have to install. Once I install also am getting error

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filepreview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/filepreview) to generate thumbnail. It's using [unoconv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unoconv) to generate a thumbnail of most of the file types (exclude image/video).